# Python generating repmat using each column individually

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of shape 3x3 which looks something like:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array(([1,2,3],[11,12,5],[4,9,1]))
>>> A
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [11, 12,  5],
       [ 4,  9,  1]])
```

I want to repmat one column at a time for 3 times so that I can achieve the following:

```
B
array([[ 1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3],
       [11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12,  5,  5,  5],
       [ 4,  4,  4,  9,  9,  9,  1,  1,  1]])
```

I can do a loop for each column and repmat that but I am looking for smarter way to do it as my real life array has size 5000x300

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the job of [`numpy.repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html). Quoting an example from the docs:

```
>>> x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> np.repeat(x, 3, axis=1)
array([[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]])
```